# Allowing raw_input to use items in a list as an answer

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have a list, and I want a user to be able to use a list item as their answer, and an if statement to check said list.  If I did not explain that well, this code may clear up what I'm trying to do:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
input = raw_input("Choose a letter.: ")
if input == letter in list:
    #do something
```

My question is how to set up the if statement to reference the list for an item when the player types in a list item.  A more complicated, and more relevant, example may be this:

```
spells = ['fireball', 'iceball', 'lightning bolt', 'firestorm', 'heal', 'paralyze']
equipped_spells = ['fireball', 'iceball']

print equipped_spells
attack = raw_input("Type the name of a spell you want to use.: ")
if attack == spell in spells:
    #initiate combat loop
```

I want the player to be able to type a spell from his/her equipped spells list, and have the if statement reference a global spells list, to see if the spell name is a valid spell.

Perhaps there may be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we aren't savages, only require the user to enter enough of the spell to be unambiguous.

```
spells = ['fireball', 'iceball', 'lightning bolt', 'firestorm', 'heal', 'paralyze']
equipped_spells = ['fireball', 'iceball']

print equipped_spells
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Type the name of a spell you want to use.: ").lower()
    lst = [x for x in spells if x.startswith(inp)]
    if len(lst) == 0:
        print "No such spell"
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        spell = lst[0]
        break
    else:
        print "Which of", lst, "do you mean?"

print "You picked", spell
```

---

```
['fireball', 'iceball']
Type the name of a spell you want to use.: fir
Which of ['fireball', 'firestorm'] do you mean?
Type the name of a spell you want to use.: fireb 
You picked fireball
```

Comment: Thanks for the laugh.  I appreciate the help.  Didn't think that typing in the spell name would be redundant until now, so thanks for that as well!

Answer (score 1):

Check to see whether the attack is in the list of spells:

```
if attack in spells:
```

You may also want to get its location in the list:

```
spell_pos = spells.index(attack)
```